# Corona app and device registration

Tags: android, ios, lua, app-store, coronasdk

**Hello everyone,**

im making a app for android and ios on corona, and when im testing it on my phone(iPhone 4s) **it works properly**.

But when i try to install it on a device that is not a registered device on apple developer it keeps on installing and it wont work.

is there any way to register a provisioning profile without specifying the devices? i just need the app for a small company. its internal so it wont need to go to the stores.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of iOS developer programs:

- Standard,
- Enterprise,
- University

For distributing your app within a company (so called In-House apps), you will need an [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). There's a [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/enterprise/?id=43) on that on Apple Developer portal.

The [difference](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.php) between the first two:

> The **standard** individual and standard company programs are intended
>   for developers who create free and fee-based iOS apps for distribution
>   on the App Store.
>
> The iOS Developer **Enterprise** Program is intended for companies who
>   create proprietary, in-house iOS apps for internal deployment within
>   the company only.